# RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) , displays there is no package called 'qmap'

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, qmap

[image: Screenshot of error that I am facing]

I have tried importing `qmap` tool from R in Jupyter Notebook. All the functions that I have imported from R in Jupyter aren't giving any error however the `qmap` gives an error.

How to solve this error of importing `qmap`, I have tried various methods i.e. checking various versions of R and Anaconda whether they are compatible or not, but the problem still persists.

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing to install the package `qmap`.

You can install it in R with `install.packages("qmap")` or in Python with `rpy2.robjects.r('install.packages("qmap")')`

So, in your case, you can write in Python this code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
try:
    pkg = importr("qmap")
except:
    ro.r(f'install.packages("qmap")')
    pkg = importr("qmap")
```

Comment: Hello ALez,i have tried the way you have said but still the problem persists. it says the following "RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : there is no package called 'fitdistrplus' ".

Comment: Your error now is different because related to a different library. So you solved the issue on qmap and you're missing the fitdistrplus lib. Please, follow my answer and add another piece of code replacing 'qmap' with 'fitdistrplus'.

Comment: @SaiBargav did you solve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried as you told me, but the error remains the same. I have also tried installing the fitdistrplus in the R environment it says it is successfully installed.  The error that is being displayed is as follows "Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'fitdistrplus' "